# Dagger 2 Constructor injection in this example

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I thought that I understood how dependency injection works with Dagger 2 until I looked at this project here: https://github.com/saulmm/Avengers.

```
public class CharacterDetailPresenter implements Presenter {

private final CharacterDetailsUsecase mGetCharacterInformationUsecase;

@Inject
public CharacterDetailPresenter(CharacterDetailsUsecase getCharacterInformationUsecase) {
    mGetCharacterInformationUsecase = getCharacterInformationUsecase;
}
}
//presenter methods
```

The activity where the presenter is injected:

```
public class CharacterDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements CharacterDetailView {

    @Inject CharacterDetailPresenter mCharacterDetailPresenter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    initializeDepedencyInjector();
    //
}

    private void initializeDependencyInjector() {

    AvengersApplication avengersApplication = (AvengersApplication) getApplication();

    int avengerId = getIntent().getIntExtra(EXTRA_CHARACTER_ID, -1);

    DaggerAvengerInformationComponent.builder()
        .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
        .appComponent(avengersApplication.getAppComponent())
        .avengerInformationModule(new AvengerInformationModule(avengerId))
        .build().inject(this);
    }
 //
}
```

And the module in question.

```
@Module
public class AvengerInformationModule {
private final int mCharacterId;

public AvengerInformationModule(int characterId) {
    mCharacterId = characterId;
}

@Provides @Activity CharacterDetailsUsecase provideGetCharacterInformationUsecase (
    CharacterRepository repository,
    @Named("ui_thread") Scheduler uiThread,
    @Named("executor_thread") Scheduler executorThread) {

    return new CharacterDetailsUsecase(mCharacterId, repository, uiThread, executorThread);
}

@Provides @Activity GetCollectionUsecase provideGetCharacterComicsUsecase (CharacterRepository repository,
    @Named("ui_thread") Scheduler uiThread,
    @Named("executor_thread") Scheduler executorThread) {

    return new GetCollectionUsecase(mCharacterId, repository, uiThread, executorThread);
}
}
```

I don't understand how the presenters are injected into the activities when they are not in any of the other modules. Is there something about constructor injections that I am not getting?

Answer (score 0):

So...

```
CDActivity <- CDPresenter <- CDUsecase <- [...]
```

I think you were able to follow the `UseCase` construction, since it is created by a module. If we hence ignore its dependencies, you can see the—simple enough—graph above.

The activity needs its presenter, which depends on the use case.

> Is there something about constructor injections that I am not getting?

Exactly. The presenter makes use of constructor injection:

```
@Inject
public CharacterDetailPresenter(CharacterDetailsUsecase getCharacterInformationUsecase) {
    mGetCharacterInformationUsecase = getCharacterInformationUsecase;
}
```

See the `@Inject` annotated constructor? You annotate the constructor and dagger will be able to see it. If every dependency for the object (constructor parameters) can be provided from a component, the component can also provide the object—the presenter in this case.

The activity component contains the `UseCase` (provided by the module), and it knows about the `Presenter` (annotated constructor), thus it can provide the presenter. The activity requests a presenter...and dagger just hands it over.

Dagger is but generated code. Try and have a look at the generated source files! Maybe look what dagger does under the hood!

Please make sure you really understand constructor injection, since in my humble opinion it is the mightiest thing about dependency injection and will save you hundrets of lines of code.

I also wrote an article where I try to give an overview about [dagger basics](http://blog.davidmedenjak.com/android/2016/05/04/dagger-2-introduction.html).

---

This code is actually somewhat error prone since the presenter is unscoped and will be recreated for every injection. You should—whenever possible—scope your objects. If you use constructor injection you would annotate the class itself:

```
@Activity public class CharacterDetailPresenter implements Presenter { /* */ }
```

Comment: Initially that's what I thought that Dagger created the presenter but thanks for clearly spelling it out. I'll definitely take a look at the generated code some time in the future.

Comment: Your blog doesn't show an example of how to do constructor injection. I have tried constructor injection but not working. Please have a look https://stackoverflow.com/q/45192878/5214893

Comment: @eCDroid I'll have a look after work. I really suggest you just try getting a grip on Dagger before trying to use it in your project. Open a single file, declare a bunch of package local components, modules, classes (with and without dependencies), and keep compiling. You'll quickly figure out what you can and can't do with Dagger this way. Make sure that you know when Dagger calls your constructor for Constructor Injection and when you have to register a `inject(MyClass)` method with your component to do field injection.

Comment: Thanks david. The things you have suggested, did them already. I have successfully injected objects via module and provide mechanism. Now i'm trying constructor injection.