# Dagger 2 how to perform constructor injection

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have a class

```
public class DialogUtils
{
    private Context context;

    @Inject
    public DialogUtils(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

In my activity class i have did but i'm getting null pointer exception on dialogUtils instance.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity{
@Inject DialogUtils dialogUtils;
}
```

I know how to inject dependency via module and component but not sure how to with construction injection. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't retain the activity-level component and you aren't inheriting from a superscope (application-level component) using component dependency or subcomponent, then it's the following

```
// unscoped
public class DialogUtils {
    private final Context context;

    @Inject
    public DialogUtils(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

then

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {    
    private final Context context;

    public ActivityModule (Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Provides //scope is not necessary for parameters stored within the module
    public Context context() {
        return context;
    }
}

@Component(modules={ActivityModule.class})
@Singleton
public interface ActivityComponent {
    Context context();

    DialogUtils dialogUtils();

    void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
}
```

And then

```
@Inject
DialogUtils dialogUtils;

...


     ActivityComponent activityComponent = DaggerMainActivityComponent.builder()
        .activityModule(new ActivityModule(MainActivity.this))
        .build();

    activityComponent.inject(this); // activityComponent.dialogUtils() also works
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do we also have these two methods `Context context(); | DialogUtils dialogUtils();` when only `void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);` could server the purpose?

Comment: Your approach giving an indication that for every activity i have to make a separate component and separate module? Correct or can i use some common approach

Comment: Dialogs require an Activity context, but you shouldn't store a static activity context. I can make it a bit more general-purpose for you though.

Comment: why do we have this method DialogUtils dialogUtils() while we can above the injection via inject method.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce, if using the android dagger and has application-level component using component dependency or subcomponent, etc. how the constructor injection can be done?

Answer (score 2):

On the one hand you are registering `DialogUtils` for Constructor Injection, so any component could provide it.

On the other hand an activity and other parts of the Android Framework still need to be field injected. Dagger **can't** call their constructor, and `@Inject DialogUtils dialogUtils;` will not just magically appear.

Here you have to use a component, and register a method that takes your components type as an argument. Dagger will then create the method to inject your activities fields.

```
@Component MyComponent {
  inject(LoginActivity activity);
}
```

To inject the fields you still have to create your component, and call the `inject(loginActivity)` method.

```
void onCreate(...) {
  MyComponent component = // create the component

  // dagger does some heavy lifting here
  component.inject(this);

  dialogUtils.doSomething(); // not null, we just injected our fields
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In your example `MyComponent` doesn't show any relation with DialogUtils. So how would calling `component.inject(this)` will inject `dialogUtils` variable.

Comment: David can you please show a complete solution example for my problem. Also how would my parameter of the constructor `@Inject
    public DialogUtils(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }` i.e context would be injected? or how could i provide because my class is not  a module i'm only using constructor injection. Please reply