# Is there a way to use injectors in a non-(Activity,Service,Fragment, Application) class

Tags: android, dagger-2

We're using Dagger2 in our application.  I am trying to do a room database and I am writing the repository code, but I would like to inject application context and the DAO for the class.

I have a feeling that you can only do Dagger injection in Fragments, Activities, Services, Applications, etc.

Here's what I have:

```
class DownloadsDataRepositoryImpl : IDownloadsDataRepository, HasAndroidInjector {

      @Inject
      lateinit var androidInjector : DispatchingAndroidInjector<Any>

      @Inject
      lateinit var downloadsDao: DownloadsDao

      override fun androidInjector(): AndroidInjector<Any> = androidInjector
      init { 
         androidInjector()
      }

}
```

But I'm sure it's not going to work.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Before asking if you can, ask if you should. The reason for using field injection on activities, etc., is that the framework requires them to have a no-arg constructor. Is a Room repository required to have a no-arg constructor? If not, just use constructor injection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated, dagger-android is just a tool to help injecting specific framework classes that you can't have control on it's creation.

The proper approach is to use simple [construction injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45192878/dagger-2-how-to-perform-constructor-injection).

To be more direct on how you should expose it on your `@Component`, I would need more code, specifically on what you have on your activity/fragment, but here is a crude example (that I did not tested, if there are minor errors, you can fix them following the compiler error messages):

First, you will have some object that exposes your DAO. Probably it's room?

```
@Entity(tableName = "download_table")
data class DownloadEntity(
    @PrimaryKey
    val key: String
)

@Dao
interface DownloadsDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM download_table")
    fun load(): List<DownloadEntity>
}

@Database(
    entities = [DownloadEntity::class], version = 1
)
abstract class DownloadRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val downloadsDao: DownloadsDao
}
```

Now we will create a crude repository that is build with `@Inject` annotation. Dagger will take care of building this object for us. Notice that I am not using dagger-android for it:

```
interface IDownloadsDataRepository

class DownloadsDataRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    val downloadsDao: DownloadsDao
) : IDownloadsDataRepository
```

How to expose it to your activity/fragment/service requires more details on your implementation. For example, if it's inside a `ViewModel` or a `Presenter` that is annotated with `@Inject` or you are accessing directly on your activity will result in different implementations. Without more details, I will suppose that you are accessing the repository directly on your activity:

```
class DownloadActivity : FragmentActivity() {

    @Inject
    lateinit val repo: IDownloadsDataRepository

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DaggerDownloadComponent.factory().create(this).inject(this)
    }
}
```

Now we need to instruct Dagger on how to:

1. Bind your concrete DownloadsDataRepositoryImpl to the IDownloadsDataRepository interface that the activity requires
2. How to provide the dependencies to build DownloadsDataRepositoryImpl

For this we will need a [module](https://proandroiddev.com/how-modules-work-in-dagger-2-643be6939b51):

```
@Module
abstract class RepositoryModule {

    //We will bind our actual implementation to the IDownloadsDataRepository
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindRepo(repo: DownloadsDataRepositoryImpl): IDownloadsDataRepository


    @Module
    companion object {

        //We need the database to get access to the DAO
        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideDataBase(context: Context): DownloadRoomDatabase =
            Room.databaseBuilder(
                context,
                DownloadRoomDatabase::class.java,
                "download_database.db"
            ).build()

        //With the database, we can provide the DAO:
        @Provides
        @JvmStatic
        fun provideDao(db: DownloadRoomDatabase): DownloadsDao = db.downloadsDao
    }
}
```

With this, we can finish the last part of our puzzle, creating the `@Component`:

```
@Component(
    modules = [
        RepositoryModule::class
    ]
)
interface DownloadComponent {

    fun inject(activity: DownloadActivity)

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(context: Context): DownloadComponent
    }
}
```

Notice that I did not use any `dagger-android` code, I don't think it's useful and causes more confusion than necessary. Stick with basic dagger2 constructs and you are fine. You can implement 99.9% of your app only understanding how those constructs works:

`@Module`, `@Component` and `@Subcomponent`

**Edit**: As stated in the comments, probably you will need to properly manage the [scope](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-CF0BGA-3w) of your repository, specially the DB creation if you are actually using Room.

Comment: To accomplish this, you create a new component instance, and don't use any scopes at all. What if I do need scoped providers? Surely I can't just create a singleton component inside `Activity.onCreate()` then. This answer assumes that Repository is stateless, and DB instance has no overhead of creation (as it would be recreated each time on rotation, etc). Although it is true that yes, the QA wanted to use constructor injection instead.

Comment: All relevant points, but I think that explaining scopes is an accessory concept for his question. Adding this to the answer would require further explanation that is better explained in the second link I used as reference in my answer.

Comment: As I stated in my answer, this was not supposed to be a functional implementation, but only a sketch on how to constructor inject his repository instead of relying on dagger-android.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you implemented dagger, but here is an example how you can provide context to non activity class.

Suppose you have AppModule class, so there you can add provideContext() method:

```
@Module
class AppModule(app: App) {

    private var application: Application = app

    @Provides
    fun provideContext(): Context {
        return application
    }
}
```

and here is non activity class written in Kotlin:

class Utils @inject constructor(private val context: Context) {
..
}

And that's it, just rebuild j

Answer (score 1):

> I have a feeling that you can only do Dagger injection in Fragments, Activities, Services, Applications, etc.

You were correct to assume that before Dagger-Android 2.20, but not after 2.20+.

Now you can create a `@ContributesAndroidInjector` for any class, which will generate an `AndroidInjector<T>` for that `T` for which you added `@ContributesAndroidInjector`.

This means that there is a multi-binding that allows you to get an `AndroidInjector<T>` for a `T`, and this is what `HasAndroidInjector` does for you.

So the following worked for me in a different scenario (for member-injecting Workers in work-manager, instead of creating a multi-binding and a factory):

```
@Keep
class SyncWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {
    init {
        val injector = context.applicationContext as HasAndroidInjector
        injector.androidInjector().inject(this)
    }

    @Inject
    lateinit var apiService: ApiService
```

and

```
@ContributesAndroidInjector
abstract fun syncWorker(): SyncWorker
```

---

HOWEVER in your particular case, none of this is required.

Dagger-Android is for member-injecting classes using an auto-generated subcomponent, that you typically need only if your injected type is inside a different module, and therefore you can't directly add `fun inject(T t)` into your `AppComponent`, OR you don't see your `AppComponent`.

In your case, simple constructor injection is enough, as you own your own class.

```
@Singleton
class DownloadsDataRepositoryImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val downloadsDao: DownloadsDao
): IDownloadsDataRepository {}
```

Which you can bind via a module

```
@Module
abstract class DownloadsModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun dataRepository(impl: DownloadsDataRepositoryImpl): IDownloadsDataRepository
}
```

And otherwise you just create your component instance inside `Application.onCreate()`

```
@Component(modules = [DownloadsModule::class])
@Singleton
interface AppComponent {
    fun dataRepository(): DownloadsDataRepository

    @Component.Factory
    interface Factory {
        fun create(@BindsInstance appContext: Context): AppComponent
    }
}
```

And

```
class CustomApplication: Application() {
    lateinit var component: AppComponent
        private set

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        component = DaggerAppComponent.factory().create(this)
    }
}
```

Then you can get it as

```
val component = (context.applicationContext as CustomApplication).component
```

Though technically you may as well create an extension function

```
val Context.appComponent: AppComponent
    get() = (applicationContext as CustomApplication).component

val component = context.appComponent
```

Comment: I think you forgot to explain to him on how to expose your component. If it's a private variable, how do you intend to use it on your Activities / Fragments / etc?